# Impersonation of User from visualforce

Tags: login-errors

I am looking to do impersonation of Users other than standard LoginAs function from Visualforce.

Please give thoughts on this and directions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of impersonation are you trying to do? save that record as the user, show data as the user would see it, login as that user?

Comment: I would like to Login as that User.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render a VF Page as another user, you'll probably want to obtain their Session Id, then use an HTTP callout to render it. You can use a Cookie and pretend to be a browser:

```
String sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId(); //you need THEIR sid
String url = 'https://c.na1.visual.force.com/apex/Vf';

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(url);
request.setHeader('Cookie', 'sid=' + sessionId + ';');
request.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
return response.getBody();
```